# BIND 9 transfer of domain zones problems

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

```
Bind reconfiguring on tiff using rndc
Bind reconfiguring on ns2 using rndc
Error reconfiguring bind on ns2: rndc: neither /etc/rndc.conf nor /etc/rndc.key was found
```

I use CPanel. Is my problem that I need to allow transfers via IP of server in named.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like wherever you're running the command, it doesn't have an "rndc key" available to tell "ns2" that it needs to reload the configuration.

Presumably CPanel should take care of the configuration of keys, if CPanel knows the two servers are supposed to work together for NS duties...